# Variable undefined when calling callback within useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook in react which consumes a javascript class. This javascript class establishes a websocket connection to an external system. When new data arrives 'onUpdate' is getting called.

```
function WebSocketProvider({ children, user }) {
  const ws = useRef(null);
  const channels = useRef({});

  const subscribe = (channel, callback) => {
    channels.current[channel] = callback;
  };

  const unsubscribe = (channel) => {
    delete channels.current[channel];
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    ws.current = servConn;
    servConn.namespace = "mobile.0";
    servConn._useStorage = false;

    servConn.init(
      {
        name: "mobile.0", // optional - default 'vis.0'
        connLink: "http://10.0.31.17:8084", // optional URL of the socket.io adapter
        socketSession: "", // optional - used by authentication
      },
      {
        onRefresh: function () {
          window.location.reload();
        },
        onUpdate: function (id, state) {
          if (channels.current[id]) {
            channels.current[id](state);
          }
        },
        onError: function (err) {
          //console(_('Cannot execute %s for %s, because of insufficient permissions', err.command, err.arg), _('Insufficient permissions'), 'alert', 600);
        },
      }
    );
  });

  return (
    <WebSocketContext.Provider value={[subscribe, unsubscribe]}>
      {children}
    </WebSocketContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { WebSocketContext, WebSocketProvider };
```

My problem is that `channels.current[id](state);`is getting called but on the other side the variable is always undefined.

```
export default function WeatherCard() {
  const [subscribe, unsubscribe] = useContext(WebSocketContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    //0_userdata.0.pv_current_consumption
    subscribe("0_userdata.0.pv_current_consumption", ({ message }) => {
      console.log(message);
    });
  });

  return (
    <div className="test">
     
    </div>
  );
}
```

The weird thing for me is that a `console.log(state)` in my WebSocketProvider shows me the content of the state variable. But `console.log(message);` in my WeatherCard shows undefined.

Do I miss something?

Comment: `useEffect` should have a dependency array and should return a cleanup function. Otherwise it can run infinitely many times

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Just added it. But this does not solve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(message) => {` instead of `({ message }) => {`?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you!